# Process csv file from upload

Tags: csv, go, go-gin

I have a gin application that receives a post request containing a csv file which I want to read without saving it. I'm stuck here trying to read from the post request with the following error message: `cannot use file (variable of type *multipart.FileHeader) as io.Reader value in argument to csv.NewReader: missing method Read`

```
file, err := c.FormFile("file")
if err != nil {
    errList["Invalid_body"] = "Unable to get request"
    c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
        "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
        "error":  errList,
    })
}

r := csv.NewReader(file) // <= Error message

records, err := r.ReadAll()

for _, record := range records {
    fmt.Println(record)
}
```

Is there a good example that I could use?

Comment: You have to [Open](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#FileHeader.Open) the part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first read the file and header

```
csvPartFile, csvHeader, openErr := r.FormFile("file")
if openErr != nil {
    // handle error 
}
```

then  read the lines from the file

```
csvLines, readErr := csv.NewReader(csvPartFile).ReadAll()
if readErr != nil {
  //handle error 
}
```

you can go through the lines looping through the records

```
for _, line := range csvLines {
        fmt.Println(line)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have mentioned, you should `Open()` it first.
The latest version of `gin.Context.FromFile(string)` seems to return only two values.
This worked for me:

```golang
func (c *gin.Context) {
    file_ptr, err := c.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        c.Status(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity)
        return
    }
    log.Println(file_ptr.Filename)
    file, err := file_ptr.Open()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        c.Status(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    records, err := csv.NewReader(file).ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        c.Status(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity)
        return
    }
    for _, line := range records {
        fmt.Println(line)
    }
}
```